# For Java assignment "x=y", does a Java compiler requires that x's declared type is the supertype of y's (including the same type)?

Tags: java, types, casting, superclass

Formulated in another way:

could you give an example assignment of JAVA, x=y, such that the declared type of "x" is not a supertype of that of "y"?

Recall that the declared type is "T" if x is declared as "T x". (supertype includes "the same type" by convention.)

Comment: Plz tell the reason of the -1

Comment: honestly, no. Maybe it's my way to formulate the problem like this if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In assignment the LHS must be the type or the RHS or a **super** type.
With supertype also covariant array types are meant: String[] to Object[] (never use that!).
Or **widening** (primitive types) may take place: assigning an `int` to a `float`.
Or **boxing** may happen: Integer to int, int to Integer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, according to the Java language specification, below. See the **bold** text.

> Assignment of a value of compile-time reference type S (source) to a
>   variable of compile-time reference type T (target) is checked as
>   follows:
>
> If S is a class type:
>
> - **If T is a class type, then S must either be the same class as T, or S must be a subclass of T, or a compile-time error occurs.**
> - If T is an interface type, then S must implement interface T, or a compile-time error occurs.
> - If T is an array type, then a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If S is an interface type:
>
> - If T is a class type, then T must be Object, or a
>     compile-time error occurs.
> - If T is an interface type, then T must be
>     either the same interface as S or a superinterface of S, or a
>     compile-time error occurs.
> - If T is an array type, then a compile-time
>     error occurs.
>
> If S is an array type SC[], that is, an array of
>   components of type SC:
>
> - If T is a class type, then T must be Object, or
>     a compile-time error occurs.
> - If T is an interface type, then a
>     compile-time error occurs unless T is the type java.io.Serializable or
>     the type Cloneable, the only interfaces implemented by arrays.
> - If T is
>     an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, then a
>     compile-time error occurs unless one of the following is true:
>
>   - TC and
>       SC are the same primitive type.
>   - TC and SC are both reference types and
>       type SC is assignable to TC, as determined by a recursive application
>       of these compile-time rules for assignability.

Comment: I may misunderstand something. The bold part gives a positive answer to the question I think?

Comment: It means: for **T x = S y** to work, the type of y must be the type of x or a subtype. Or, in another words, the type of x must be a supertype of the type of y.

Answer (score 1):

Well, depends on what you mean by "supertype". However, if used as a general OOP term:
`Object[] arr = new Integer[5];`

For discussion on why this is a flaw of the type system, please see for example http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety

Answer (score -1):

Certainly:

```
Object o = new Object();
Object o2 = o;
```

In this example, the type of o2 is not a proper supertype of the type of o. However as far as the intention of the question (probably) goes, see the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, supertype includes "the same type" by convention.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention in your question whether you were referring to proper supertypes or not.